# php - insert record into SQL database

Tags: php, sql

hi there i am using the following php code to insert a record into a SQL database... but the code doesnot work..

```
<?php
include_once("config.php");

$academicDate = $_POST['aDate'];
$academicDescription = $_POST['aDescription'];
$academicTitle = $_POST['aTitle'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO academicnews (id, newsDate, newsDescription, newsTitle) VALUES ('', $academicDate, $academicDescription, $academicTitle)";

 if (mysql_query($sql)) {

echo "Record Aded to Database. Hit OK to add more";

 }else{
     echo "Failed to add record to database";
 }

?>
```

note that the id is an auto_increment number..... and the config.php file code is..

```
<?php
########## MySql details (Replace with yours) #############
$username = "root"; //mysql username
$password = "s1j55b123456789"; //mysql password
$hostname = "localhost"; //hostname
$databasename = 'dominie'; //databasename

$connecDB = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)or die('could not connect to database');
mysql_select_db($databasename,$connecDB) or die(mysql_error());

?>
```

how do i solve this (it echos failed to add record) problem... any help would be appreciated.. thanks in advance... :)

Comment: What doesn't work? You need to do a better job of describing your problem.

Comment: it echos failed to add record...

Comment: Use  `mysql_error()` to know better what's going wrong. Might just be a quote in the title / descriptions, since your unescaped query is easily breakable

Comment: [Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ). FYI, you are also wide open to [SQL injections](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it, please:

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO academicnews (newsDate, newsDescription, newsTitle) VALUES ('$academicDate', '$academicDescription', '$academicTitle')";
```

Answer (score 1):

What I see is that you don't use quotes around your values, when they are not numeric values.

Try:

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO academicnews (id, newsDate, newsDescription, newsTitle) VALUES ('%', '$academicDate', '$academicDescription', '$academicTitle')";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO academicnews (newsDate, newsDescription, newsTitle) VALUES ($academicDate, $academicDescription, $academicTitle)" ;
```

Comment: looks like MillaresRoo hit the enter a few seconds before me.. ;)